# Remove block from layout XML in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml

In Magento 1 I could remove a block added by a layout file by adding this in my layout-block

```
<remove ="block_id_here" />
```

How can I do the same for Magento 2?
As a practical exercise, let's say I have my own module from which I want to remove the dashboard block from the admin dashboard page.
The block is added from `app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml` using this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard" name="dashboard"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I assume I need to create the file `view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml` in my module, but what do I need to put in it?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In more recent versions of Magento2, the remove method is now:

`<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is important to know in case you are trying to do something more than just remove an element. Changing the namespace to layout instead of `page_configuration` may not allow you to do everything you are needing to do.

Comment: This worked for me. The odd thing is however, that the example stated on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html actually uses the `<remove />`-tag. Error in the documentation?

Comment: @GielBerkers Very likely an error in the documentation -- be sure to let them know https://github.com/magento/devdocs

Comment: How can i do this a phtml file

Answer (score 11):

In the most recent dev branch of magento 2, try create view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-dashboard" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="dashboard" remove="true"/>
```

Source https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?l=xml&q=remove&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you want to remove the title block from the success page. 
First you will need to find the xml that is responsible for that specific page in our case it will be `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml`

And in this file you will have the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Success Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success.print.button" template="Magento_Checkout::button.phtml"/>
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Thank you for your purchase!</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success" template="Magento_Checkout::success.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="order.success.additional.info" label="Order Success Additional Info"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Registration" name="checkout.registration" template="Magento_Checkout::registration.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You will now need to extend this xml in your theme `app/design/frontend/.../.../Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml`
And inside it reference the block you need to remove `page.main.title` and add `remove="true"` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

If you wish to remove a specific block from all cms pages you can achieve this by extending the default xml `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`
in you theme folder `app/design/frontend/.../.../Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```