# Magento 2: Remove block depending on a config setting

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I'm trying to remove a block from a certain page (be it frontend or backend) but only if a certain config flag is set to `true`.
Let's take an example.
I want to remove the block with the name `dashboard` from the admin dashboard.

The block is defined in `adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml` file from the `Magento_Backend` module:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard" name="dashboard"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

[Thanks to Adam's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/82830/146) I can do this in the `adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml`

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="dashboard" remove="true"  />
</body>
```

But I want to take it up a notch and remove this block only if the config setting with the path `dashboard/settings/remove` has the value `1`.
A layout xml approach would be awesome, but I will take an observer approach also.

Comment: Marius, you know the same thing is available for events.xml?I mean I want to execute my observer if configuration is enable

Comment: If you want to go with a `helper` class, see
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237179/magento-2-i-want-to-add-ifconfig-in-override-block-xml?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237179/magento-2-i-want-to-add-ifconfig-in-override-block-xml?rq=1)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this with layout either but here is an example of a way you can do it with observers (providing they extend the Template block)...

Create your events.xml in etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="view_block_abstract_to_html_before">
        <observer name="remove_block" instance="[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Model\Observer\RemoveBlock" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create the observer

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RemoveBlock implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if ($block->getType() == 'Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard') {
            $remove = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'dashboard/settings/remove',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );

            if ($remove) {
                $block->setTemplate(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the _toHtml checks to see if there is a template. If there isn't it returns ''.

**EDIT**

After some more digging i have found a way to do this further up the chain.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="remove_block" instance="[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Model\Observer\RemoveBlock" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And the observer...

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RemoveBlock implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout */
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();
        $block = $layout->getBlock('dashboard');
        if ($block) {
            $remove = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'dashboard/settings/remove',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );

            if ($remove) {
                $layout->unsetElement('dashboard');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work, but only for blocks that use templates. It applies to the example I provided, but still, if there are blocks that extend the AbstractBlock and not the Template block this will not work. +1 for the good starting point.

Comment: You are correct. After some more digging i found you can do this earlier in the process. Answer updated. I have left my original there for reference.

Comment: Thanks this is a useful answer. The problem is it means the logic will be fired on every page load as it's using the event "layout_generate_blocks_after". Do you know how to only run it on certain page loads e.g. loading a category page (event is "catalog_controller_category_init_after" but the layout cannot be accessed)?

Comment: Really?! We have to do an observer to remove or not conditionally a block? this is ridiculous, just saying.

Comment: Observers should not manipulate data I think ...

Answer (score 8):

Normally it should be done with `<action />` tag :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="dashboard/settings/remove">
        <argument xsi:type="string">dashboard</argument>
    </action>
</referenceContainer>
```

**EDIT :**

Only problem is unsetChild only accept alias. You cannot use block name.

Other solution: rewrite Magento Framework to be able to use ifconfig with remove="true"

1- Create your own module.

2- Add a new file to override Magento Framework : (eg : `/Vendor/Module/Override/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php`)

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Override\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader;

use Magento\Framework\App;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Layout;

/**
 * Block structure reader
 */
class Block extends \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface
     */
    protected $scopeResolver;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Layout\ScheduledStructure\Helper $helper
     * @param Layout\Argument\Parser $argumentParser
     * @param Layout\ReaderPool $readerPool
     * @param InterpreterInterface $argumentInterpreter
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver
     * @param string|null $scopeType
     */
    public function __construct(
        Layout\ScheduledStructure\Helper $helper,
        Layout\Argument\Parser $argumentParser,
        Layout\ReaderPool $readerPool,
        InterpreterInterface $argumentInterpreter,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver,
        $scopeType = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($helper,
            $argumentParser,
            $readerPool,
            $argumentInterpreter,
            $scopeType
        );
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->scopeResolver = $scopeResolver;
    }

    protected function scheduleReference(
        Layout\ScheduledStructure $scheduledStructure,
        Layout\Element $currentElement
    ) {
        $elementName = $currentElement->getAttribute('name');
        $elementRemove = filter_var($currentElement->getAttribute('remove'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        if ($elementRemove) {
            $configPath = (string)$currentElement->getAttribute('ifconfig');
            if (empty($configPath)
                || $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag($configPath, $this->scopeType, $this->scopeResolver->getScope())
            ) {
                $scheduledStructure->setElementToRemoveList($elementName);
            }
        } else {
            $data = $scheduledStructure->getStructureElementData($elementName, []);
            $data['attributes'] = $this->mergeBlockAttributes($data, $currentElement);
            $this->updateScheduledData($currentElement, $data);
            $this->evaluateArguments($currentElement, $data);
            $scheduledStructure->setStructureElementData($elementName, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

3- Add di.xml file to override magento file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block"
       type="Vendor\Module\Override\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block" />    
</config>
```

4- Now you can use ifconfig in layout combined with remove :

```
<referenceBlock name="content" remove="true" ifconfig="path/to/myconfig" />
```

**This example is for Block, but you can do the same for container if you override the method containerReference() of /Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Reader/Container.php**

Comment: I think rewriting the Framework is the best solution, don't know why magento don't have this by default.

Comment: Magento2.3.4 - Rewriting the Framework is working for mode - default and production. ifconfig not working for developer mode. :-|

Answer (score 7):

From the [technical guidelines](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html#14-events):

> 14.1. All values (including objects) passed to an event MUST NOT be modified in the event observer. Instead, plugins SHOULD BE used for modifying the input or output of a function.
>
> 14.3. Events SHOULD NOT change a state of observable objects.

### So here is a plugin solution for this:

Declare the plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock">
        <plugin name="remove_block" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\RemoveBlock" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Define the plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class RemoveBlock
{
    const BLOCK_NAME = 'block_to_be_removed';

    const CONFIG_PATH = 'your/path';

    private $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function afterToHtml(AbstractBlock $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($subject->getNameInLayout() === self::BLOCK_NAME && $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::class)) {
            return '';
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Like in the [answer from Smartie](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99199/70510) I tried to plugin further up the chain into `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder::build` with an `afterBuild()` method but this will lead into an endless recursion because `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout::getBlock` and `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout::unsetElement` both call `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder::build` again.

Answer (score 2):

"ifconfig" attribute of a "block" node in layout allows you to link block to value in store configuration.

"ifconfig" processing happens in `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool::buildStructure`

Comment: It won't work with "referenceBlock" though. It will only work when you're adding a new block.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the block, and then conditionally add your block. For example, in your `adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml` you can put:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard" name="dashboard" remove="true"/>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard" name="my_dashboard" ifconfig="dashboard/settings/remove"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Note that you should change the logic of `dashboard/settings/remove` setting. It should be `dashboard/settings/show`, and if it is set to 1 your block will be shown.