# Is it possible to display an XML Block based on an IF?

Tags: xml, phtml, magento-2.2.5

I use the below code in a module within `catalog_product_view.xml` to display a new Tab on the Product Page.

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="example.tab" template="Vendor_Module::example.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Example Title</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I'd like to know if you can Display/Hide this based on a Product Attribute? Normally, I'd embed an IF within the phtml file. But wondered if it could also be done this way instead?

Reason why I ask, is because I don't want the Tab to load if a Product Attribute = `Yes`. As the information might not be relevant.

Comment: You can do that Block level and system config  changes support at  if condition at layout

Comment: Can you reference some examples?

Comment: for layout https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99841/4564

Comment: ifconfig is only used to check for an admin config is 0 or 1 .

Answer (score 0):

You can do that even though its not recommended in my opinion .

plus what you have done already , you can create an after plugin for the public method Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Tabs::getTabs() which will return an array of the tabs that will be added to the page .

Then you can use the registry to get the current product object and check for the attribute you want , if yes then you can just remove that tab (title in your case) from the returned array in getTabs() ,or else return it as it is .