# i need remove block with system config condition magento2?

Tags: magento2, blocks

I have tryed but not working proparly

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" ifconfig="quote/general/display_addtocart" />
```

System.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
      <tab id="test" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
            <label>test</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="quote" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Quote</label>
            <tab>test</tab>
            <resource>Comapanyname_modulename::comapanyname_modulename</resource>

            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="quote_button_name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Quote Button Name</label>
                </field>
                <field id="submit_button_name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Submit Button Name</label>
                </field>
                <field id="form_title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Form Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="display_addtocart" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Add to Cart Button</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Show your system.xml

Comment: <field id="display_addtocart" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Add to Cart Button</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>

Comment: Add system config to your question with section, group and field.

Comment: @SHPatel i have attached system.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.form.content" ifconfig="quote/general/display_addtocart" >
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
</referenceBlock>
```

instead of

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" ifconfig="quote/general/display_addtocart" />
```

Comment: remove block perfect but config condition not apply

Comment: What is saved display_addtocart system config values?

Comment: store 'o' or' 1'

Comment: i have resolve this issue from below link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99199/43587

Comment: Okay I think remove condition not work based on ifconfig