# Removing totals block from mini cart in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout-update

I've read [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80425/remove-block-from-layout-in-magento-2) already, however I'm failing to apply it properly.

I want to remove the totals section from the mini-cart. To track down the block I've enabled path hints.

[image: Minicart with path hints enabled]

So it seems the block of interest is `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals` and the template of interest is `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/totals.phtml`. Searching the code I found this line

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="cart/totals.phtml">
```

in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`. So in my custom module trying to remove it, I've created this file `vendor/my-module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

That doesn't remove the totals section, however I feel like I'm on the right track because two exercises succeed in my attempt

- Editing `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` and removing the declaration for the `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals` block
- Editing `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/totals.phtml` and removing `cart-totals` div.

So I seem to be working with the correct block and template, but my layout update doesn't work; any idea why? Note, caching is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals" remove="true" />`

This is not true. Remove attribute stop the default cart functionality in magento2. Use display="false" attribute in xml file.

Solution:
Create default.xml file at view/frontend/layout/default.xml in custom module.

`<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals" display="false" />`

## Default .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals" display="false" />
 </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting point about using `display=false` instead of `remove=true` for blocks pertaining to the cart. However putting the *default.xml* file as you have show does not hide the block for me, so something still isn't working correctly.

Comment: my side is working. show the code  plz

Comment: Hmm, it seems I needed to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` for it to take effect, whether I place it in *default.xml* or *checkout_cart_index.xml*. Does that sound right?