# How to remove reference container block from layout?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, page-layouts

I want to remove the block from `referenceContainer`. I have gone through the below link:

[Remove block from layout in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80425/remove-block-from-layout-in-magento-2)

And tried to remove as per the above answer:

```
<referenceBlock name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
```

But it's removing whole container. I want to remove the particular block.

Below is my `layout.xml` code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

I want to remove only `footer.store_switcher` and `footer.newsletter`. I am using the below code to remove both blocks.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer.store_switcher" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="footer.newsletter" remove="true"/>
```

`default.xml` file path:

**E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\Vender\Theme\Magento_Theme\layout**

Please help me.

Comment: you have did right for remove block, after doing last, <referenceBlock name="footer.store_switcher" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="footer.newsletter" remove="true"/>not working for you?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya could you please elaborate more? I can't understand what you are saying. No both are not working for me.

Comment: I think you have did right xml code for remove footer.store_switcher and newsletter. May be check after clear cache

Comment: I have cleared the cache lots of time after write code in xml.

Comment: you have to do it inside default.xml file not inside layout.xml file

Comment: I have write the remove statement in the `default.xml` but it's still coming.

Comment: could you please show me the default.xml file absolute path?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya please see the file path in the updated question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can remove using that code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: Lot of help me for today +V

Comment: Also Use  :   <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>