# How to remove Sell link from footer links in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.1.6, third-party-module, footer-links

There are a footer link name 'Sell' is coming. I need to know their module name in magento 2. Here is the screenshot of the link on checkout pages.

[image]

This link take the user to  `site-address/marketplace/`. Here is the screenshot of marketplace page.

[image]

I want to remove it from footer links. Can any body has any clue that where this block is coming?

Comment: can you insert screenshot of the page?

Comment: @RohanHapani. i have updated the question with screen shot.

Comment: You can remove this link by getting id using inspect element. put this code in document ready function . so when page load then link will be hide. Ex. :- $("#id_of_the_link_div").css("display","");

Comment: @RohanHapani. thanks. Can you please let me know that how can i remove it using layout in magento 2?

Comment: You can get reference from this link => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80425/remove-block-from-layout-in-magento-2

Comment: @RohanHapani. I know that procedure but not know the name of the block and module of the block.

Comment: I m not aware about magento 2.1.6 .. It may be available in module-cms default.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the link through layout, you can simply remove it from default.XML file and if you have added it through widgets, go to your admin panel, click content > widget and delete that widget in which you have added this link.

Comment: it is by default. I don't know where it is coming. I searched in whole code but i didn't found it.